# 301 redirect in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have done 301 redirect for my old URL to new URL using redirectPermanent in mvc
but unfortunately, I have wrongly mapped old url to new URL.

is there any option to remove the 301 permanent redirect status code from URL?
or is there any way to change it to old url?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can revert the change on the server side. However you can clear your browser cache and ask your clients (if any) to do the same, which will clear the 301 redirect.